# Delaying Loop iteration and creating Views

Tags: swiftui, timer

I am very new to SwiftUI. I am trying to create an app for my daughter to help her with learning how to add. I am doing this by using a number line. The number line is created using a horizontal `Divider` as my base and then vertical `Divider`s to mark each number on the number line.

For example, if she needs to add 4 + 8, the app will show her how you start at 4 and count up 8 until you get to 12. In the app this is accomplished through a `ForEach` loop which starts at 4 and runs until 12. Each time the loop iterates, it produces the vertical divider plus a text field making the number.

Here is what the end product looks like:

[iOS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/demzG.png)

This is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct GenerateNumberLineView: View {
    var firstNumber: Int
    var secondNumber: Int
    var counter: Int
    var opacityTest: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            Divider()
                .frame(width:300, height: 4)
            
                .overlay(.pink)
            
            ForEach(firstNumber..<(secondNumber+firstNumber+1), id: \.self) { number in
                var count = 0
                
                let offSetter = -150 + (number-firstNumber) * 30
                
                VStack{
                    
                    Divider().frame(width:4, height: 30,
                                    alignment: .leading)
                    .overlay(.pink).offset(x:CGFloat(offSetter))
                    
                    Text(String("\(number)")).offset(x:CGFloat(offSetter))
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    GenerateNumberLineView(firstNumber: 4, secondNumber: 8,counter: 0,opacityTest: 0.0)
}
var updateTimer: Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true,
                         block: {_ in
        
        let maximumn = num2 + numb
        
        if self.counter == maximumn - numb {
            self.updateTimer.invalidate()
        } else {
            self.counter += 1
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is the whole number line shows up at one time and I would like to delay each iteration for a second, so that it looks like the app is doing the counting up to 12 from 4. I tried wrapping the code in the loop in the following dispatch code:

```
let seconds = 0.25
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds)
{...code inside loop}
```

... but got this error:

> No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression' <<errors

My most successful attempt was to call the struct in another view and then implement a timer:

```swift
GenerateNumberLineView(firstNumber : minNum, secondNumber: maxNum, counter:counter,opacityTest: opacityTest).onAppear(perform: { let _ = self.updateTimer })
```

This works 76% of the way. The problem is it only displays one number on the screen. It shows 4 and then 4 disappears then it shows 5.

I want it to show 4. 4 stays on the screen it pauses for a beat then shows 5 pause then shows 6 and so on until 12. So the number line looks like the picture I attached but the process of getting to there was displayed to the user.

Comment: A ForEach isn’t a loop per se, it is a View for all intents and purposes, views are synchronous and cannot be delayed. You can add models to an array asynchronously but the body/View will be synchronous no matter what, it will redraw every time a model for  row is added to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your timer, as a publisher, in the SwiftUI view. Increment a `@State` (let's call this `currentNumber`) each time the timer fires, until it reaches `secondNumber`.

Change the range for the `ForEach` to `firstNumber..<(firstNumber + currentNumber + 1)`, and the numbers now appear one after another.

You can add `transition` and `animation` modifiers to add an animation when a new number appears.

```
let firstNumber: Int
let secondNumber: Int

@State var currentNumber = 0

let timer = Timer.publish (every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack{
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width:300, height: 4)
            .overlay(.pink)
        
        ForEach(firstNumber..<(firstNumber + currentNumber + 1), id: \.self) { number in
            let offSetter = -150 + (number-firstNumber) * 30
            VStack{
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:4, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .overlay(.pink)
                Text("\(number)")
            }
            .offset(x:CGFloat(offSetter))
            .transition(.opacity)
        }
    }
    .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        currentNumber += 1
        if currentNumber == secondNumber {
            timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
        }
    }
    .animation(.default, value: currentNumber)
}
```

Comment: @kevincampbell If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!